# Flutter: fit dynamic number of rows inside container without scroll

Tags: flutter

I have a container that takes full height and some width:

```
Flexible(
   flex: 2,
   child: myComponent(),
),
```

Inside myComponent(), I need to display different rows (and columns inside them).
To make it more clear, this is going to display a calculation like this:

```
 64545
+ 4232
______
 68777
```

So here we'll have:

- Row() --> Column() --> Cellx5
- Row() --> Column() --> Cellx6 (one's empty)
- Row() --> Column() --> Cellx5

The calculation could be more difficult with decimals, higher numbers, etc. So it's totally dynamic.
Each cell will have a `Card` with a dynamic `Text` (the number):

```
Card(
        elevation: selectedNumberBox == index ? 5 : 2,
        shadowColor: selectedNumberBox == index ? Colors.orange : Colors.grey,
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: AutoSizeText(
            '2',
            style: TextStyle(),
            maxFontSize: 32,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

That part is fine, but I don't know how to fit the rows into the parent component. I have tried `GridView` and `Table`, but I can't find a way to make this work.

I don't want scroll, it needs to fit vertically make the rows smaller if we have more numbers (not possible but if we only had only one, it'd take full height).

I had this working before on a website and what I did was check the width and height of parent and child. With that, calculate how much bigger the child was in % and apply a zoom `property` in css. With that I had the child element take either full width or height (whatever it was bigger).